# Limit Scope to single file in Google Auth JWT client for Google service account

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-functions, google-authentication, service-accounts, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm am using a service account to generate an access token to access certain sheets in my google drive. That access token will be sent to the client-side user and using that users will access my sheets. But different users have access to different sheets and I want them to **prevent access to other sheets with the same access token**. Currently, the service account has access to all the file used by my app.

For generating access token I use `googleapis`'s `google.auth.JWT` module. I use Firebase cloud functions as my backend with Node version 10

Here is my code,

```
        try {
            const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
                key.client_email,
                null,
                key.private_key,
                ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',],     // drive scope
            );

            const accessToken = await jwtClient.authorize();

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            res.status(500).json(error)
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: check the drive.file scope think it will limit to only files created by the app itself.

Comment: The current answer is correct. Your pattern is an anti pattern: you send the identity token of your service account outside and anyone can access to document on behalf the service account. You don't know who access the document, who change them,... Only one piece of advice: DON'T DO THAT!

Answer (score 1):

If the permissions of the service account gives the token full access to every file in the folder these tokens  would allow to read other documents too. I think you may workaround this granting a specific user permissions to a set of documents by changing the permissions of the file itself, instead of providing a generic access token. This page of the [Drive documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing#node.js) describes how to change permissions at a file level and provides some Node.js samples.

Comment: Yes, I tried your method. But it need the user to have a google account right? I'm trying to do this without the user login through his google account and it also requires us to go through Google app verification process which they never replied yet. Thanks for the answer btw.

Comment: @MaheeGamage Yes, they need google account, see this [answer](https://support.google.com/drive/thread/58179611?hl=en)